# How do I run .scptd from Terminal in Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

I have a `.sctd` file in mac, i want to run it from terminal without opening the AppleScript Editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`osascript`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html) to run apple scripts in the terminal.